# Q table creation and update for dynamic action space

Tags: q-learning

I am trying to implement a Q-learning algorithm for energy optimization. It is a finite MDP with states represented as 6 dimensional vectors of integers. The number of discrete values in each index of the state vector varies from 24 to 90.

The action space varies from state to state and goes up to 300 possible actions in some states, and below 15 possible actions in some states.

If I could make some assumptions (just for the purpose of testing the model), I could reduce the states to about 400 and actions to less than 200.

How can I construct a Q-table for such an environment? I am not sure how to approach this in Python, how to prevent the table containing lots of impossible state/action combinations, or prevent the agent trying to take those unwanted actions.

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps you are confusing time step id with state identity? E.g. the symbol $s_1$ could mean the first state in a set of (in your case 24) states, or it could mean the state at $t=1$. Your mention of a horizon and a "state vector" implies that really you mean the latter, because if you really had 24 states, there would be no need for any vector of information. In which case, could you explain how complex that vector is? It may be too much to use tabular RL

Comment: Okay I see. So what I have is that there is excel data showing state variables like time and corresponding power demand and grid tariff, which is to be read at every time step, all through to the horizon T (24 hours). I decided to have all those in one state vector, so there are up to 24 of them. But since I am using batteries (2 of them, and I do not want to lump their parameters), I decided to append the energy levels of each to the state vector (they are vital in deciding the optimal action). An action vector contains power values committed to the load and the two batteries.

Comment: Hence, the next state is gotten by reading the static state variables from the excel table, then updating and appending to that vector the new battery energy. I decided to deal with optimization constraint by ensuring all possible action vectors allowed are those that are within constraints, so that the agent learns within the boundaries (deterministic environment).

Comment: OK. Could you give a rough indication of number of dimensions per state vector and how many discrete values per dimension? If continuous variables, how realistic is it to use discrete values for them (e.g. would it lose really important details of the problem)?

Comment: Wow! Your questions have made me understand my problem even much better. So the the state vectors have 6 elements. The first four elements of the state vector has 24 discrete values (can be 48 or 96 depending on the choice of time steps), while the next two range from 10 to 90, discretized in steps of 1 (to fit the load which takes integer values) and from 10 to 60 (also discretized in steps of 1). Now each state has a different number of possible actions.

Comment: The discretization is okay. The action vectors are also given as integers, and perfectly fit the intended goal of the optimization scheme.

Comment: OK, those numbers mean you do have an astronomical number of distinct states. This is quite normal for real problems, but it makes using a Q table impossible. If it is possible to use a Q function, approximated using linear regression or a neural network, then it may still be doable. Is that an option for you (i.e. you have not been asked directly to produce a Q table, and you know enough about linear regression or neural networks that you could do this technically)?

Comment: I have not been restricted. I just thought Q-table approach was going to be the simplest way to test my model. Now if I could make some assumptions (just for the purpose of testing the model) I could reduce the states to about 400 and actions to less than 200. Can this be possible to implement on a Q-table and get optimal results?

Comment: Sure that gives you < 80,000 state/action pairs. You will need a simulator (or historical data) that is able to visit all pairs at least once (for 100% deterministic environment) and possibly some multiple of this (for stochastic environments). Could you clarify what is preventing you building a Q-table if you have these limited state and action ids? I wonder if you are actually asking about something else than creating a valid table.

Comment: For instance, if you knew how to build the table, would you then be able to implement one of Q learning, MC Control, SARSA? I.e. you already know enough to build a learning agent but are literally stuck on how to tabulate your state/action pairs? Or is something else the issue?

Comment: Well, there are some actions that are not allowed in some states and I cannot just see how to build the Q-table. Yes, I am new to programming, and I am using python. Could you please help me build the Q-table. How should I deal with the actions that are not feasible in the individual states? For example, if these actions remain in the table for those states, and their Q values remain unchanged once initialized to zero, would that mean that when I will be retrieving the optimal policy (in this case using the argminQ(s, a)) the function will return the actions with zero Q-values?

Comment: It won't matter much if you have non-valid entries in your Q table. At some point you have to filter down to only valid actions, but it is not usually the job of a Q table or Q function to do that. Anyhow, I have enough information to answer now, so I will try to do so later today . . .

Comment: Okay, I will be very grateful. Some of the preliminary work I am doing on the project can be accessed here: https://github.com/EArwa/Q-Learning/blob/master/States.ipynb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is a finite MDP with states represented as 6 dimensional vectors of integers. The number of discrete values in each index of the state vector varies from 24 to 90.
>
> The action space varies from state to state and goes up to 300 possible actions in some states, and below 15 possible actions in some states.

In combination, this could be over a billion state/action combinations. It is likely to be too much for running a tabular method over. The dynamic actions, changing depending on what the state is are not an issue, but the total size of such a table probably will be.

> If I could make some assumptions (just for the purpose of testing the model), I could reduce the states to about 400 and actions to less than 200.

This is a much more tractable number for creating a table. Your total number of records will be at most 80,000.

There are a couple of things worth looking at in more detail:

### Number of training examples needed

With a tabular method, as well as constructing the table, you need to collect data for each possible state/action combination. If there is some randomness in the environment, then you need to collect data from each possible state/action combination multiple times. For a table with size 80,000 this might be very fast and easy if you have a fast simulation of the environment. However, it might still not be a feasible size if you can only collect information from a single real environment and the time step represents a day . . .

You will need to check your own numbers to figure out whether this is an issue.

Perhaps even the billion plus items for your full description is not an issue if you have a fast computer and lots of memory to store the table.

### Dealing with ragged data in a table

You don't have to do this. If you have enough memory spare and want to take the easy route, you could just use a tensor description (i.e. allow all values in each dimension, and enumerate them from 0 to whatever size). See next section for how you should limit action choice.

However, it may be more efficient to do something about the ragged data.

The simplest way to do this is to generate a unique ID for each allowed state vector, and use that to reference a value in a nested hash structure, e.g. a Python `dict` of `dict`s.

A very simple ID generator would be to concatenate your state vector and action labels into a list, then convert that into a string using some kind of join function. Example in Python:

```
# Empty Q table
q = dict()

# Define an example state, action and value
state = [20,12,56,9,76,30]
action = 176
value = -2.4

# Store an example state, action and value

# This state to state_id conversion should be a re-usable function
state_id = '/'.join([str(x) for x in state])
# Example state_id is '20/12/56/9/76/30'

if state_id in q:
  q[state_id][action] = value
else
  q[state_id] = {action: value}
```

The easiest way to manage the Q table with this approach is to add entries as and when you need them. Don't pre-populate with zeros, only write action values when they are needed by your agent. That will mean that you only create table entries for state, action pairs that exist.

### Filtering action values

You will need code, that you consider to be part of the environment, that knows which actions are valid depending on the current state. This code could return the list of all possible actions. For instance you might define a function `allowed_actions(state)`. You then use that list when working with the Q table:

- When looking for a maximising action to drive a policy, look up the whole dictionary of action to value (in `q[state_id]` and [pick the max one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary))
- When you reach a new state that you have not seen before, it may be convenient to populate all possible actions from that state with zeros. Prototype Python code for doing that might look like this:

```
state_id = '/'.join([str(x) for x in state])
if not state_id in q:
  q[state_id] = { action: 0 for action in allowed_actions(state) }
```

Comment: Okay, I see. An episode consists of 24 (48 or 96 depending on size time steps) time steps, and at the end of each episode, the agent gets to the original state; but depending on the actions taken, it may or may not visit the states visited in the first episode. So you mean that every time step, I need a statement to check if the state exists in the dictionary?

Comment: @EArwa: Yes you will need to check every time you want to use the Q table, whether you have defined the entry, otherwise you will get errors. How you manage the Q table storage is not directly related to how experience is split into episodes.

Comment: If I get what you are saying; you mean that I will need a dictionary of states, and each state will have the list of actions. Does that mean that for the values associated with actions in those states, I will have another dictionary within the dictionary so that each action has its Q-value in the state it was taken?

Comment: No you only need one state index and one action index in the Q table lookup, it does not need to go deeper. `q[state_id][action_id] = value` is enough to represent $Q(s,a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a table

Comment: I am getting lost. A dictionary will only have a key and a value pair. What will be the key, and what will be the value. I also need to trace the time step ID as learning proceeds.

Comment: The time step id does not go into the Q table. Just the current value estimate. I have just written the exact code above that you would use assuming `q` is a dictionary of dictionaries. You want two levels of key for easy lookup of "all action values for this state". So `state_id` is a key in `q` that has a value of another dictionary (a sub-dictionary if you like, but of course it is just another Python `dict` object that you put under the `state_id` key). Then `action_id` is the key to this dictionary, and the value is the floating point action value that you are managing

Comment: Okay, I see. Let me try implementing that.

Comment: I have two more questions on action selection strategy (I plan to use the pursuit method) and Q-value update. Can I ask them on the comment here or you would prefer I ask it in a whole new question post?

Comment: Like with the pursuit algorithm (to balance exploration and exploitation), the greedy action has a probability say p1 of being selected, while the rest have a probability p2 of being selected, could you please show me an example code on how to enforce such conditional picking?

Comment: And the case of Q-value update, if I want the action that would give maximum reward in the next state, yet the next state is a new state which did not initially exist, and actions still have Q-value of zero, how do I go about it?

Comment: @EArwa: If my answer here has covered your original question about how to construct the Q table when the action numbers vary, and you have a new but related question, then please ask a new question on the site.

Comment: @EArwa: You should be able to find examples of what you want to do with Python, plus existing questions and answers on Stack Overflow. Basic "how do I do X in Python" questions are best there. Your question about what to do when the agent has never seen a state before would be good on Data Science or AI stack exchanges.

Comment: Okay @Neil. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry @Neil, I just learnt how to accept correct answers today.

Comment: I have implemented it, it kind of works. I just want to know how best I can initialize my q-values as in my most recent question which you correctly edited. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @EArwa: Yes I have an idea. Your update equations are both wrong in that question. Worth checking they are exactly what you are using, in case my answer there points out something you don't care about. I hope to write an answer at some point, but as always work comes first. Maybe later today :-)

Comment: I am very grateful for your help in the process. I managed to implement the algorithm and published two papers from it.